# finding the <tr> in a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a table:

```
<table id="Table">
    <tr id="tr-1">
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-2">
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-3">
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-4>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-5">
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table
```

I have code that looks for the last `<tr>` in that table

```
var ID = $("#Table tr:last").attr("id");
```

Now I want to find the id of the `<tr>` that is two `<tr>`'s back from the **ID** that I collected. The answer would be `<tr>` id="3". But what code would I write to get that answer?

Comment: Your tr's don't have ID's btw.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`:nth-last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3Anth-last-child) selector: http://jsfiddle.net/7QFDB/.

```
var ID = $("#Table tr:nth-last-child(2)").attr("id");
```

This selector is implemented in most modern browsers. For compatibility, [this jQuery plugin](https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-misc/master/jquery.ba-nth-last-child.js) can be used.

Comment: so it would actually be three. http://jsfiddle.net/7QFDB/1/ but this is great thanks!

Comment: "it is implemented via Sizzle" No, it's not. Your fiddle appears to work because Sizzle first passes a selector to the Selectors API, then checks the result before attempting to work it out on its own. This means the selector will work in any browser that natively supports the Selectors API as well as the CSS `:nth-last-child()` selector, but no other. Consequently this means it'll fail in IE < 9 and Fx < 3.5 (as opposed to working seamlessly as is usually expected of jQuery/Sizzle), because Sizzle itself does *not* implement `:nth-last-child()`.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the heads-up. I looked in the source code of jQuery and Sizzle, but I couldn't find any reference. Then, I tested the selector in Sizzle, which worked well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prev()` twice:

```
var id = $("#Table tr:last").prev().prev().attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Can get the `index()` of last row  then use that to go  any number of rows you want

```
   var lastRowIndex=  $("#Table tr:last").index();
   var different_row=  $("#Table tr").eq(lastRowIndex-2)
```